# Java FX: Update TreeView after adding an item

Tags: java, javafx

I created a program, which has a TreeViewList and an adding item in the menu.

My question is: With which function can I refresh the TreeView after I added an item?

Should I do it with an ObservableList and a ListChangeListener? Or is there an easier way?

Comment: If an ObservableList is backing the View, then the View should automatically update once you update the backing list.

Comment: please read (and try to understand) a basic tutorial on how-to-use TreeView, when stuck come back with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem